# ARGB to YUV && Color Spaces in .NET

Tags: c#, yuv, color-space, argb

I noticed that `Color` struct from `System.Drawing` represents color in **ARGB** color space. So there are some questions:

- How to convert image beetween ARGB and YUV in c#? I found formulas describing RGB to YUV conversion. So what should I do with alpha channel?
- Are there free/trial libraries that support different color spaces? Or how do I implement it myself in the best manner?
- How do I represent 'Bitmap' as 2d array with ability to iterate over it? is Inheritance  the only way to accomplish this?

That's all yet)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot directly convert argb to YUV (without loss) cause YUV contains no alpha information.

Depending on what you wanna do with the color after you have these possibilities:

- you just cut the alpha and discard the transparency
- you convert to a AYUV which contains
  also an alpha channel

[conversion between color spaces](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/colorspace1.aspx)

One possibility to convert a bitmap to a byte[] is to write it in a memorystream and read it bite wise.

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
bitmap.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Bmp);
byte[] data = stream.ToArray();
```